# Where is hudson.model.Run.Replay permission object defined?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins allows granting members (users and groups) `Run.Replay` (Run → Replay) permission by using UI:

[image: Configure Permissions]

Unfortunately, `Run.Replay` permission it is not defined in `hudson.model.Run` class. All other permissions are available:

- `Delete` → `Run.DELETE`
- `Update` → `Run.UPDATE`

Where is defined the `hudson.security.Permission` object which represents `Run.Replay` permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission is introduced by the [Pipeline: Groovy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-cps) plugin. It is defined in the `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.replay.ReplayAction` class:

```
/**
 * Attached to a {@link Run} when it could be replayed with script edits.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") // on Run
public class ReplayAction implements Action {

    [...]

    public static final Permission REPLAY = new Permission(Run.PERMISSIONS, "Replay", Messages._Replay_permission_description(), Item.CONFIGURE, PermissionScope.RUN);
```

Link to the class located in the 2.78 version: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/workflow-cps-2.78/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/replay/ReplayAction.java#L360

Comment: importing `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.replay.*` doesn't change anything. Still appears `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: REPLAY for class: hudson.model.Run`

Comment: The field is declared in `ReplayAction`, so of course it is missing in `Run` (because such field does not exist). You have to access it by using `ReplayAction.REPLAY`.